# Write a recursive function to find the smallest element in a vector(MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, recursion

> Write a recursive function to find the smallest element in a vector.
> We can not use loops but can use if statements.
> Using RECURSION is a must.

I Could Not think of any solution, the main problem was if I define a function then I have to give it some value and if I do so then whenever recursion occur it will again reset the value of that variable.

Comment: The smallest element of an array is the smallest of: (1) the first element or (2) the smallest of the rest of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions which in the worst case reduce the problem size by 1 will cause the recursive stack to have O(length(array)) growth. An example of this would be when you filter the array to yield values less than the first element when the array is in descending order. This will inevitably lead to stack overflow for sufficiently large arrays. To avoid this, you want to use a recursion which splits the problem of size n into two subproblems of size n/2, yielding O(log(length(array))).

I'm not a Matlab user/programmer, so I'll express the algorithm in pseudo-code. The following assumes that arrays are 1-based and that there is a built-in function `min(a,b)` which yields the minimum of two scalars, `a` and `b`. (If not, it's easy to replace `min()` with if/else logic.)

```pseudocode
function min_element(ary) {
  if length(ary) == 1 {
    return ary[1]
  }
  split ary into first_half, second_half which differ in length by no more than 1
  return min( min_element(first_half), min_element(second_half) )
}
```

This could alternatively be written using two additional arguments for the `lo_index` and `hi_index` to search between. Calculate the midpoint as the integer average of the low and high indices, and make the two recursive calls `min_element(ary, lo_index, mid)` and `min_element(ary, mid+1, hi_index)`. The base condition is when `lo_index == hi_index`, in which case you return that element. This should be faster, since it uses simple integer arithmetic and avoids creating sub-arrays for the subproblems. It has the trade-off of being slightly less friendly to the end user, who has to start the process by calling `min_element(ary, 1, length(ary))`.

If the stack limit is 500, you'll be limited to arrays of length < 500 using linear stack growth algorithms. With the divide-and-conquer algorithm described above, you won't get stack overflow unless you have an array of length ~2<sup>500</sup>, much bigger than any array you could actually create.

Answer (score 0):

```
function miminimumis=minimumval(k)
aa=k(1);
k=k(k<k(1));
if length(k)==0
    miminimumis=aa;
  
else
%      this line gives the recursion
     miminimumis=minimumval(k);
   
end

end
```

here we  create a new array which consists of elements only smaller than the first element. if this array is empty then it means that first element is min, if not we do the same for the new array unless we reach an empty array. the recursion is provided by using the same function in the definition of the function.

Comment: This would run into stack limitations if, for instance, the array is large and contains unique values in decreasing order.

Comment: could you give me an example array

Comment: I described it. But as a concrete example, an array of size 1000 containing 1000, 999, 998,…, 3, 2, 1 would blow out Matlab’s default stack size of 500. I’m not a Matlab user, but that’s what a web search turned up for `matlab stack limit`.

Comment: tried that for 1e4 sized array with decreasing elements as you described. the time for this algorithm to find the min is  1.483353 seconds.

Comment: Then the web is not telling the truth about default stack limits for recursion in Matlab, because 1e4 > 500.

Comment: you can try it yourself.